# how should i make my project to be responsive with the css?

Tags: css, responsive-design

i tried to style my screen size in the @media tag but the contain in my page is still not responsive at all. What can i do to make it responsive other than bootstrap? The below code is my css code that i added into my project. Thank you in advance.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)  {
body{
position: absolute;
width: 411px;
height: 823px;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;

background: #00644C;

font-family:Inter;
}

}



.container {
  width: 309px;
  clear: both;
}

.container input {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}


label {
color: #FFFFFF; 
  display: flex !important; 
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  

 
}
.btn.btn-block{

background: #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 2px;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 20em !important;
    height: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Please share more details, what you want to achieve ? Because in the code you are adding absolute position to body tag and fix width as well .  You can remove the media and remove fix widths replace it with some percentages . If you want to apply this style below 600px than you can media.  And don’t use absolute . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code into your `head` section of your html. This gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.

The `width=device-width` part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).

The `initial-scale=1.0` part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```